# Using JSON in ColdFusion application

Tags: javascript, json, coldfusion

I have a website that has a front-end view for non-registered users and then a portal view for registered users.

I am trying to re-vamp the product navigation, wanting to make it easily maintainable for adding/removing links I want this to be in JSON format.

I am using Mura CMS with ColdFusion.

Probably a fairly simple thing I am trying to do but cannot find any examples online.

I have my JSON data as below:

```
    {
    "category" : [
        {
            "name" : "digital stickers",
            "products" : [
                {
                    "name" : "round digital stickers",
                    "urlPublic" : "index.cfm/digital-stickers/round-stickers",
                    "urlPortal" : "tab=round digital stickers"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "square digital stickers",
                    "urlPublic" : "index.cfm/digital-stickers/square-stickers",
                    "urlPortal" : "tab=square digital stickers"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "Litho stickers",
            "products" : [
                {
                    "name" : "round litho stickers",
                    "urlPublic" : "index.cfm/litho-stickers/round-stickers",
                    "urlPortal" : "tab=round litho stickers"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "square litho stickers",
                    "urlPublic" : "index.cfm/litho-stickers/square-stickers",
                    "urlPortal" : "tab=square litho stickers"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see I have the category name, which I will use to determine the 'Digital Stickers' and 'Litho Stickers'.  I will then loop through the data to pull out the different products names and depending if portal user or public user will take the data to insert into the URL.

To get started I just need to know how to link this into my ColdFusion application. Not a massive ColdFusion Guru yet, more into my JavaScript languages, so any help here would be highly appreciated.

From there I should be good to go.

Just in case that is a bit vague, like html documents link the stylesheet with a  tag - how do you link the JSON to the ColdFusion document? Is it like including a ?

Comment: ColdFusion has the `serialiseJSON(data)` and `deserializeJSON(json)` which will convert between JSON and native CF datatypes. https://cfdocs.org/deserializejson

Comment: I will be using the deserializeJSON(json).  Say my JSON file is named productInfo.json and is in the same file location as my coldfusion file - how do I call in the json file?

Comment: How would you include a file into your code using any programming language? You need to read it right. [cffile action = "read"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7374.html)

Comment: json might not be the best way to store your data.  What is your plan for adding more categories and/or products?

Comment: Adding more categories/products I would just add them into the JSON file, from here the code should manage to loop through any number and output them to the page? @DanBracuk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around for a while I found a good example on the help.adobe website.

This line of code accesses the JSON data and pulls it in for use

```
<!--- Get the JSON Feed ---> 
<cfhttp url="http://localhost:8500/project/JSON_FILE.json">
```

After that I Deserialized it with

```
<cfset cfData=DeserializeJSON(theData)>
```

Then to test I had everything coming back correctly I  used a cfdump

```
<cfdump var="#theData#">
```

I wanted to spit out only specific data so I did a cfloop to loop through the data array

```
<h2>Categories</h2>
<cfloop array="#dataArray#" index="elem">
    <!--- print out value for demo purposes --->
    <cfoutput>
            <h3>#elem.name#</h3>
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

This printed out 'Digital Stickers' and 'Litho Stickers' as expected.

My resources were [Adobe Help - getting and deserializing the JSON](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-79e4.html) and [Experts Exchange - Loop over deserialized JSON](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28279574/Loop-over-deserialized-json.html).